# What reputation systems are implemented on Ethereum?

Tags: dapps

I'm looking into finding some sort of reputation system on Ethereum. Are there any projects out there already that do this? I found a DEVCON1 video about reputation systems and a few people discussing it briefly, but not really any basic proofs of concepts.

Is Augur something that I should look at for this?

Comment: The best reputation system is rather subjective. Can you clarify what you are trying to do and what your needs are from a reputation system?

Answer (score 6):

**iudex**

[iudex](http://iudex.github.io/) by Alex Beregszaszi, Thomas Bertani - smart contract based reputation system at working prototype stage, see more on [Ether Camp](http://iudex.on.ether.camp/ide.html) or on [Github](http://iudex.github.io/frontend/). via [State of the DAPPS](http://dapps.ethercasts.com/) - (new DAPPS arriving daily, well almost)

**Augur**

[Augur](http://www.augur.net/) have more on [What is Reputation?](http://www.augur.net/blog/what-is-reputation) the cryptographic token used in their system is known as REP, or Reputation. Further expansion of [How does Reputation (REP) work?](https://augur.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204038791-How-does-Reputation-REP-work-) plus a number of further articles on [Reputation](https://augur.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=reputation&commit=Search)

**Synereo**

[Synereo](http://www.synereo.com/) are running with REO, a few details in section 1.3.1 in their  [White Paper](http://www.synereo.com/whitepapers/synereo.pdf) and further details [in their blog](http://blog.synereo.com/) essentially the timings from the video discussions.

[image]